# Some linear constraints seem to be ignored in function NMinimize with Mathematica 8

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, constraints, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to minimize a non-linear function of four variables with some linear constraints. Mathematica 8 is unable to find a good solution giving complex values of the function at some point in the iteration. This implies that one or some contraints are not being enabled in the process. Is this a bug or limitation of the optimization function ?

Function to minimize is

```
ff[lxw_, lwz_, c_, d_] := - J1 (lxw + lwz) - 2 J2 c +
 T (-Log[2] - 1/2 (1 - lxw) Log[(1 - lxw)/4] - 
 1/2 (1 + lxw) Log[(1 + lxw)/4] - 
 1/2 (1 - lwz) Log[(1 - lwz)/4] - 
 1/2 (1 + lwz) Log[(1 + lwz)/4] + 1/2 (1 - d) Log[(1 - d)/16] + 
 1/8 (1 + 2 c + d - 2 lwz - 2 lxw) Log[
   1/16 (1 + 2 c + d - 2 lwz - 2 lxw)])
```

where

```
T = 10;
J1 = 1;
J2 = -0.2;
```

are constant parameters. Then I try

```
NMinimize[{ff[lxw, lwz, c, d],
 2 c + d - 2 lwz - 2 lxw  >= -0.999 && 
 -0.999 <= lxw <=  0.999 &&
 -0.999 <= lwz <= 0.999 && 
 -0.999 <= c <= 0.999 &&
       d <= 0.9999}, {lxw, lwz, c, d}]
```

with the result

> NMinimize::nrnum: "The function value 5.87777[VeryThinSpace]-4.87764\ I\n 
>      is not a real number at {c,d,lwz,lxw} = {-0.718817,-1.28595,0.69171,-0.932461}.

I would appreciate if someone can give a hint at what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  Clear[ff];
  ff[lxw_, lwz_, c_, d_]  /; 2 c + d - 2 lwz - 2 lxw  >= -0.999 :=
     < your function def >
```

This will cause the cause the function to be unevaluated in case NMinimize takes an excursion out of bounds. Sorry i cant test this from here..  If that doesn't do try asking on mathematica.stackexchange.com

Aside, why use <=.999 instead of simply < 1 ?
It just might help if you fix that too ( use integer 1, not 1. )

Answer (score 0):

The warning is appearing because at the values given in the warning the last term in `ff` is complex, due to taking the log of a negative number, i.e.

```
{c, d, lwz, lxw} = {
   -0.7188174745559741`,
   -1.2859482844800894`,
    0.6917100913968041`,
   -0.9324611085040573`};

Log[1/16 (1 + 2 c + d - 2 lwz - 2 lxw)]
```

> -2.5558 + 3.14159 i

```
1/16 (1 + 2 c + d - 2 lwz - 2 lxw)
```

> -0.0776301

In *Mathematica* 9 a result is produced in addition to the warning :-

```
{-4.90045, {c -> 0.94425, d -> -0.315633, lwz -> 0.900231, lxw -> -0.191476}}
```

I.e.

```
{c, d, lwz, lxw} = {
    0.9442497691706085`,
   -0.31563295950647885`,
    0.900230825707721`,
   -0.1914760216875171`};

ff[lxw, lwz, c, d]
```

> -4.90045

Comment: Thank you @george and Chris for your help. The first proposal didn't work. I still don't know why the algorithm seems to go out of bounds but a satisfactory workaround was proposed in [(http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42999/nminimize-go-out-of-bounds-on-some-linear-constraints)] by Daniel Lichtblau.

Comment: @danielstariolo - Thanks for the follow-up info.